# display php variable for image in submit button

Tags: php

I have a php page which is working good and displays a list of mp3s available. When the user clicks on the selection , the data is submitted to another php to process. Here's the form

```
 ?php
 $suragif= "./images/"  . $mp3name . ".gif" ;

 if (!empty($titlname)) {

echo "<form method='POST' action='play.php' >
<input type='hidden' name='titlname' value= $titlname />
<input type='hidden' name='mp3name'  value= $mp3name />
<input type='hidden' name='mp3gif'   value= $mp3gif />

<input type='submit' class='headfont' name='submit' value=$suragif>
</form>";
?>
```

What I need is instead of using titlname in submit button , whether I can use image.
How do I pass variable to img src , images have exact same name with extension of .gif and stored in ./images/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='play.php' >
<input type='hidden' name='titlname' value='$titlname' />
<input type='hidden' name='mp3name'  value='$mp3name' />
<input type='hidden' name='mp3gif'   value='$mp3gif'/>

<input type='submit' class='headfont' name='submit' value='$titlname'>
</form>";
```

Comment: Sorry didnt work. button shows as ./images/name.gif.

Comment: You must show me the variables then. What should be displayed in there?

Comment: it should display image of mp3name.gif instead of text

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is how I fixed it.  <input type='image' class='headfont' name='submit' src='$suragif' >

Comment: No problem ;) Enjoy...